# How does one append/change the values of matrix_basis directly in blender using the python API?

Tags: python

I have a set of 3 orthonormal vectors(x_vec, y_vec, z_vec: know values) defining a particular position in the global frame, I want to align an Empty's XYZ axes to the above mentioned orthonormal vectors. I tried rotations and all sort of stuff but it doesn't seem to align properly. I figured that changing the matrix_basis of the empty directly to that of the 3 orthonormal vectors' rotation matrix is the most efficient way to do it, but I can't seem to modify the values of the matrix_basis of the Empty.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: matrix_basis is a two dimensional array and you can adjust each element manually if you wish. [mathutils](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix) might help. Is the rotation order correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, adjusting each element is not supported in blender.

Comment: Does for me, `object.matrix_basis[1][1] = 0.5` changes the objects y scale to 0.5. `mathutils` does make it easier to work with matrices without having to know what indices are needed for each component.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's pretty straight forward.

let the 3 orthonormal vectors be represented as a matrix,
 rotation_matrix = [x_vec, y_vec, z_vec] (3x3 normalized rotation matrix)

Now, use mathutils to convert this to a set of Euler rotations and Voila!

rotation_in_euler =  rotation_matrix.to_euler()

obj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'

obj.rotation_euler = rotation_in_euler